# Miner crashes at Invalid header on mined block

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

Please Help !
I have a geth client running a private chain, everytime I do miner.start() it starts processing any previously committed transactions then it prints the following then crashes completely. It doesn't process any more transaction when I send/receive any ether.

```
INFO [04-05|17:10:44]  mined potential block                  number=23 hash=077500…801662
INFO [04-05|17:10:44] Commit new mining work                   number=24 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=140.185µs
INFO [04-05|17:10:45] Successfully sealed new block            number=24 hash=b7d1ba…11081e
INFO [04-05|17:10:45]  block reached canonical chain          number=19 hash=c42dc1…94d958
INFO [04-05|17:10:45]  mined potential block                  number=24 hash=b7d1ba…11081e
INFO [04-05|17:10:45] Commit new mining work                   number=25 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=132.192µs
INFO [04-05|17:10:46] Successfully sealed new block            number=25 hash=be9ac2…c5861c
INFO [04-05|17:10:46]  block reached canonical chain          number=20 hash=7e9132…28bf08
INFO [04-05|17:10:46]  mined potential block                  number=25 hash=be9ac2…c5861c
INFO [04-05|17:10:46] Commit new mining work                   number=26 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=164.022µs
INFO [04-05|17:10:47] Successfully sealed new block            number=26 hash=e6b517…6e284e
INFO [04-05|17:10:47]  block reached canonical chain          number=21 hash=4e3a79…0164b9
INFO [04-05|17:10:47]  mined potential block                  number=26 hash=e6b517…6e284e
INFO [04-05|17:10:47] Commit new mining work                   number=27 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=158.024µs
INFO [04-05|17:10:47] Successfully sealed new block            number=27 hash=0254f9…5abbf9
ERROR[04-05|17:10:47] Invalid header on mined block            err="block in the future"
```

I'm running the following version of GETH

Geth
Version: 1.6.0-unstable
Git Commit: cc303017c3f145441e583b5bb10ee3070b44cc50
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.8
OS: linux

Comment: Do all the machines in your network have their clocks sync'd to the correct time?

Comment: Yes. I was actually just running one node. and when I try to start the miner on that node, it shows that error and stops.

Comment: Initally I had 2 instances of geth running on the same machine, with different ports. I used addPeer to connect them and everything was fine. Until I do miner.start( ) the miner processes some transactions then halts. I have to restart it again.